# Making gatling generate random data per request using a feeder

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to get gatling to create random data per POST request. I've followed a few posts on stackoverflow and other places. I came up with this scenario -

```
def randomUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("user" -> randomUuid))

def createPostRequest = {
  http("createuser")
    .post("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .body(StringBody("${user}"))
    .check(status.is(201))
}

val scn = scenario("some load test")
  .feed(feeder)
  .forever(exec(createPostRequest))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
  .maxDuration(20 minutes)
```

However, when I run this code it just calls my feeder once to create a single UUID and just re-uses the same UUID throughout the load test.

I created the code above after following [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/6p1za3/any_gatling_experts_here/dkm64nc/). I'm using gatling 2.2.5. Here's my sbt config -

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  private val gatlingHighcharts = "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling- 
  charts-highcharts" % "2.2.5"                    % "test"
  private val gatlingTest =       "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % gatlingHighcharts.revision % "test"

  val gatlingDependencies = Seq(gatlingHighcharts, gatlingTest)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you don't call `feed` inside a loop, typically your `forever` one, you will indeed only generate one single value per virtual user.
If what you want is to have unique values per loop iteration, move the `feed` call inside the loop.

Comment: Ran into the same thing. Suspected that might be the case... it's an easy mistake to make, apparently. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

in your setUp, you're only creating one user - so your scenario is only getting executed once, meaning that 'feed' only occurs once before you start looping over your request.

change your scenario to be

```
val scn = scenario("some load test")
.feed(feeder)
.exec(createPostRequest)
```

and make your setUp (replacing 100 with whatever number of users you want)

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(100)))
```

Comment: The "users" here indicates parallelism, and not number of executions. The . forever is what tells gatling to repeat the scenario until the duration is reached. More info here - https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/simulation_setup/#throttling